# is it proper to name the images for Non-English Alphabet language for SEO aims by urlencode() output

Tags: php, utf-8, seo, urlencode, non-english

1. In Turkish, we call 'şarkı' for 'song'.
2. `urlencode('şarkı') == '%C5%9Fark%C4%B1'`
3. most of users in our country will search for 'şarkı' in image search
   (not for sarki or song)

if I name my image `'%C5%9Fark%C4%B1.png'` in ftp, Can I be sure that all engines (most popular ones are google, yandex here) will exactly understand that visitor searched for `'şarkı'` which is matching with `'%C5%9Fark%C4%B1.png'` at some image search result page?

note: I don't know if it's related however I utilize utf-8 in HTML, php connection language setting and also MySQL tables.

thanks

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you name your image `'%C5%9Fark%C4%B1.png'`, it will be named so, and you would have to link to it using the name:

```
<img src="images/%25C5%259Fark%25C4%25B1.png" />
```

As you see, `%` changed to `%25`.

Name it as it is in ftp, then either `urlencode()` or output it in utf-8, browsers will urlencode themselves.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't understand your answer. Do you mean: (1) name it as `şarkı.png` and send into FTP. (2) while linking in php use `urlencode('şarkı.png')` in `href="<!--php output-->"`part

Comment: Yes, I meant it this way. But even `urlencode('şarkı.png')` shouldn't be necessary if the encoding on the page is correct.